# Cannot read property of null in json api of a picture url

Tags: javascript, rest

I'm working on an api using javascript, and in representing values of json data into html, and for simplicity, i have something as:

```
data.maps((post)=>{
const item = `<img src="${post.user.pictures.sizes[1].link}"/>`
})
```

In the json object, i have 10 posts and one of them has value of null for the pictures url. and it doesnt render. it gives me the error cannot read property of null of pictures.

I've tried the `item.pictures.url=null? "":item.picture.url` but it didnt work. I'm new to rest api, so i'm guessing that from using the method get you don't get to update the data. I'm thinking of replacing any value of null to an generic url of my choosing. but i dont know where to start. Any input will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `item.pictures.url=null` means _set_ `item.pictures.url` to `null`. Obviously, it will be `null` after that. What is the exact error message? What exactly is `post`?

Comment: post is the json object that i fetched from vimeo api and i'm mapping through it to display data in html. it's not the whole code, but just posting a snippet of where the problem is.  And the exact error is `cannot read property of null pf pictures` and in the json object they're are 10 posts  and each one with its objects. One of the posts has picture url set to null as a value. so thats why it renders the error

Comment: No, that’s not the exact error. Please [edit] your question and post both the _exact_ error message, and part of the JSON structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.maps((post)=>{
    const item = post.user.pictures != null ? '<img src="' + post.user.pictures.sizes[1].link + '" />' : '<img src="your-no-pictures-img.jpg" />';
})
```

Comment: But then maybe it's undefined and not null. I update the condition for nulls and undefined

Comment: it's null. And I've included a picture.

Comment: the null is item.pictures and not item.pictures.url as you said :S

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the path of json object. I didn't include the exact name of object for simplicity sake. It is not about whether its the proper path its about how to render an image path when you have a url of value of null

Comment: Thank you. That was close to the solution, but it majorly helped. you can just remove `the post.user.picture.size>0 ` and i will have it marked as a solution. :)